# Can't set custom paperclip path using :url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor  :current_account
  attr_accessible :post_id
  attr_accessible :image

  belongs_to :post

  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => { :medium => ["500x375>", :jpg], :thumb => ["70x70#", :jpg] },
                    :processors => [:thumbnail, :compression],                    
                    :url => "/system/#{Photo.current_account}/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
                    :path => ':rails_root/public:url'
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_attachment_file_name :image, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 7.megabytes

  before_post_process :rename_image

  def rename_image
    puts "== Photo.current_account: #{Photo.current_account} == "
    extension = File.extname(image_file_name).downcase
    self.image.instance_write :file_name, "#{Time.zone.now.to_i.to_s}#{extension}"
  end

end
```

I'm using rails 3 and paperclip on a multitenant app. I'm trying to set the path of the image based on the value of Photo.current_account but it does not seem to work. But when I puts it in the rename_image it works. What could be wrong? I set this up so that when the user uploads, the destination will be based on the user's subdomain during that request. The Photo.current_account already holds the subdomain info from the controller.

```
http://subdomain1.lvh.me:3000/system//photos/images/000/000/708/original/1417662848.jpg?1417662848
```

Currently, the output is like the line above in which as you can see after system/ its a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using paperclip interpolation by adding the code below in the current model.

```
Paperclip.interpolates :current_acct do |attachment, style|
  Photo.current_account
end
```

Then used

```
 :url => "/system/:current_acct/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```